# Camel JMS Component with Spring on Weblogic Server

Tags: spring, jms, weblogic, apache-camel

I could not found any decent, clear example to learn JMS component with Spring configuration. So I wrote something like this:

```
<bean id="weblogic" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://${ip}:${port}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jmsJndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/cdrPreMO-connfact-jndi"/>
</bean>

<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <camel:endpoint id="jmsQueue" uri="weblogic:queue:jms/cdrPreMO-queue-jndi"/>

    <route>
        <from ref="jmsQueue"/>
        <bean ref="test" method="writeFile"/>
        <to uri="log:errors?level=ERROR"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

But it gives the exception :

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'weblogic.jms.backend.jms'. Resolved 'weblogic.jms.backend'; remaining name 'jms'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:252)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode.lookupHere(ServerNamingNode.java:182)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:206)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:214)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEManager.destinationCreate(FEManager.java:287)
    ... 8 more
```

JMS Conf is true(ip port and jndi names). It is getting the  connection, and the session but gives the exception
Could someone tell me what are my mistakes?

Thanx

EDIT: fix applied according to the comment of Claus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved but with a workaround. I still do not know what the problem really is but, instead of weblogic create its own destination by itself, I gave the responsibility to spring like:

```
<bean id="weblogic" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfiguration" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${ip}:${port}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jndiDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jmsJndiTemplate"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfiguration" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jndiDestinationResolver"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jmsJndiTemplate"/>
    <property name="jndiName" value="jms/cdrPreMO-connfact-jndi"/>
</bean>
```

It is working now.

Answer (score 3):

The Camel endpoints should refer to "weblogic" as the component name.

```
<camel:endpoint id="jmsQueue" uri="jms:queue:jms/cdrPreMO-queue-jndi"/>
```

Should be

```
<camel:endpoint id="jmsQueue" uri="weblogic:queue:jms/cdrPreMO-queue-jndi"/>
```

As that is the name you gave the JMS component in the id attribute of the < bean > tag, eg

```
<bean id="weblogic" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Claus.Really valuable info to me. But the exception is still the same. it still says: Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'weblogic.jms.backend.jms'. Resolved 'weblogic.jms.backend'; remaining name 'jms'

Comment: By the way I do not know where the package name weblogic.jms.backend.jms came from.I think the problem could be about weblogic jar itself.

Comment: Yeah JNDI lookup can be painful to get working. Do you have a queue name on the weblogic server that is named "jms/cdrPreMO-queue-jndi". It seems the stacktrace is about looking up/creating JMS destination.

Comment: The queue module's JNDI name is jms/cdrPreMO-queue-jndi and it exists. When I am trying to create my own destination instance, it spring does not give any exception. But I do not know what "weblogic.jms.backend.jms" package is. Exception does not give me anything

Comment: Claus, you saved my day!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although question is pretty old, posting this solution for other users if they get this error. I ran into the this issue on Camel 2.19 version while trying to look up weblogic queue in weblogic 12c version. The lookup that happens here is most likely not a typical JNDI lookup when resolving queue destination in Weblogic. 
The end point uri should contain the queue details as follows :

```
jms_server_name/jms_module_name!queue_name
```

For example if queue name is TestRequestQueue, created under a module named sample_jms_module and the JMS server is named sample_jms_server in Weblogic, then the uri would need to be as follows :

```
<camel:endpoint id="jmsQueue" uri="weblogic:queue:sample_jms_server/sample_jms_module!TestRequestQueue"/>
```

In the prefix portion of the uri `weblogic:queue:`, the component name can be anything as long as it refers to the created component. It needn't necessarily be `weblogic`. For example, if the JmsComponent is named as `test-jms`, the uri will need to be declared with prefix as `test-jms:queue:` .

Name of the JMS server in weblogic can be obtained from Weblogic console by navigating to the below path :
   Services -> Messaging -> JMS Servers

Name of the queue, not the JNDI name, can be obtained from Weblogic console by navigating to the queue and clicking on Monitoring tab. This tab shows the destination name of the queue in the name column.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run apache camel jms component in weblogic 12c with next configuration. The key is the jndi name for the queue.
It must be ./module_name!queueName. './' means local jms server.

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactoryBean" jndi-name="dpxcomConnectionFactory"/>


 <bean id="dpxcomJMSConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryBean"/>   
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="50"/>

    </bean>


Route definition:
    from("jms:queue:./DPXCOM!"+config.getMainQueueName()+"?concurrentConsumers="+config.getConcurrentConsumers()
              +"&maxConcurrentConsumers="+config.getConcurrentConsumers()+"&jmsMessageType=Text&testConnectionOnStartup=true&connectionFactory=dpxcomJMSConnectionFactory&consumerType=Simple")
        .setHeader("jmsMessage").body()
        .process(new VerifyJMSMessageProcessor())
        .choice()
        ..
        ..
end();
```